# Fixing Column Issue When Importing Data in R

Tags: r, loading, read.csv

Currently having an issue importing a data set of tweets so that every observation is in one column

This is the data before import; it includes three cells for each tweet, and a blank space in between.

```
T   2009-06-11 00:00:03
U   http://twitter.com/imdb
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-11 16:37:14
U   http://twitter.com/ncruralhealth
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-11 16:56:23
U   http://twitter.com/boydjones
W   listening to "Big Lizard - The Dead Milkmen" ♫ http://blip.fm/~81kwz
```

```
library(tidyverse)

tweets1 <- read_csv("tweets.txt.gz", col_names = F, 
                    skip_empty_rows = F)
```

This is the output:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_character()
)
Warning message:
“71299 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual            file
 35  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'tweets.txt.gz'
 43  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'tweets.txt.gz'
 59  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'tweets.txt.gz'
 71  -- 1 columns 5 columns 'tweets.txt.gz'
107  -- 1 columns 3 columns 'tweets.txt.gz'
... ... ......... ......... ...............
See problems(...) for more details.
”
# A tibble: 1,220,233 x 1
   X1                                   
   <chr>                                
 1 "T\t2009-06-11 00:00:03"             
 2 "U\thttp://twitter.com/imdb"         
 3 "W\tNo Post Title"                   
 4 NA                                   
 5 "T\t2009-06-11 16:37:14"             
 6 "U\thttp://twitter.com/ncruralhealth"
 7 "W\tNo Post Title"                   
 8 NA                                   
 9 "T\t2009-06-11 16:56:23"             
10 "U\thttp://twitter.com/boydjones"    
# … with 1,220,223 more rows
```

The only issue are the many parsing failures, where problems(tweets1) shows that R expected one column, but got multiple. Any ideas on how to fix this? My output should provide me with 1.4 million rows according to my Professor, so unsure if this parsing issue is the key here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `read_csv` is for comma-separated text files. From your output, it looks like your data are tab-separated. Try `read_tsv`.

Comment: True, tsv is cleaner, but my preferred output for the problem is one column; moreover, tsv leads to more parsing errors for this odd data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you.

### data

```
data <- 'T   2009-06-11 00:00:03
U   http://twitter.com/imdb
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-11 16:37:14
U   http://twitter.com/ncruralhealth
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-11 16:56:23
U   http://twitter.com/boydjones
W   listening to "Big Lizard - The Dead Milkmen" ♫ http://blip.fm/~81kwz'
```

For a large file, `fread()` should be quick. The `sep = NULL` is saying basically just read in full lines. You will replace `input = data` with `file = "tweets.txt.gz"`.

```
library(data.table)

read_rows <- fread(input = data, header = FALSE, sep = NULL, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

### processing

You could just stay with `data.table`, but I noticed you in the `tidyverse` already.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
```

Basically I am grabbing the first character (T, U, W) and storing it into a variable called `Column`. I am adding another column called `Content` for the rest of the string, with white space trimmed on both ends. I also added an `ID` column so I know how to group the clusters of 3 rows.

Then you basically just pivot on the `Column`. I am not sure if you wanted this last step or not, so remove as needed.

```
read_rows %>%
  mutate(ID = rep(1:3, each = n() / 3),
         Column = str_sub(V1, 1, 1),
         Content = str_trim(str_sub(V1, 2))) %>%
  select(-V1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Column, values_from = Content)
```

### result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID T                   U                                W                                                                         
  <int> <chr>               <chr>                            <chr>                                                                     
1     1 2009-06-11 00:00:03 http://twitter.com/imdb          No Post Title                                                             
2     2 2009-06-11 16:37:14 http://twitter.com/ncruralhealth No Post Title                                                             
3     3 2009-06-11 16:56:23 http://twitter.com/boydjones     "listening to \"Big Lizard - The Dead Milkmen\" â™« http://blip.fm/~81kwz"
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I used read_lines to get the data in the same format as my Prof has, but I will for sure be using the wider format you provided for my analysis. Do you know a handy line of code to replace blank observations with NAs?

Comment: Yeah however you want to read it works! What do you mean by blank observations? Do you mean the blank lines? You can try checking `str_length(text) = 0` and then using `if_else()` to change values with zero length to NA.